# symfony get data from array

Tags: sql, arrays, symfony1, doctrine

I'm trying to use an SQL query to get data from my database into the template of a symfony project.

my query:

```
SQL:
SELECT l.loc_id AS l__loc_id, l.naam AS l__naam, l.straat AS l__straat, 
l.huisnummer AS l__huisnummer, l.plaats AS l__plaats, l.postcode AS l__postcode,
l.telefoon AS l__telefoon, l.opmerking AS l__opmerking, o.org_id AS o__org_id, o.naam AS o__naam 
FROM locatie l 
LEFT JOIN organisatie o 
ON l.org_id = o.org_id
```

This is generated by this DQL:

```
DQL:
 $this->q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('l.naam, o.naam, l.straat, l.huisnummer, l.plaats, l.postcode, l.telefoon, l.opmerking')
->from('Locatie l')
->leftJoin('l.Organisatie o')
->execute();
```

But now when i try to acces this data in the template by either doing:

```
<?php foreach ($q as $locatie): ?>
<?php echo $locatie['o.naam'] ?>
```

or

```
<?php foreach ($q as $locatie): ?>
<?php echo $locatie['o__naam'] ?>
```

i get the error from symfony:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
Unknown record property / related component "o__naam" on "Locatie"
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? i dont know how to call the value from the array if the names in both query's dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine will have hydrated your results into objects corresponding to the models in your query. In your case these will be `Locatie` and `Organisatie`.  You should therefore be able to access the data as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($q as $obj): ?>
  <?php echo $obj->Locatie->naam; ?>
  <?php echo $obj->Organisatie->naam; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you have the above method in eg the `Locatie` table class and use `self::create("l")` to create your method, the object you use in the view won't need the `->Locatie` part.

**Edit**: table method example:

```
class LocatieTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function getLocaties()
  {
      $q = self::createQuery("l")
      ->select('l.naam, o.naam, l.straat, l.huisnummer, l.plaats, l.postcode, l.telefoon, l.opmerking')
      ->leftJoin('l.Organisatie o')
      ->execute();

      return $q;
  }      
}
```

You should be able to find this class (probably empty) already auto-generated in `lib/model/doctrine/LocatieTable.class.php`.  Now call it with:

```
$this->q = Doctrine::getTable("Locatie")->getLocaties();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, i cant get it to work though, if i try your foreach symfony still trows an error: Unknown record property / related component "Locatie" on "Locatie"

i currently have the query in my action.

Comment: if i remove the first line and just try the second (organisatie) i indeed does correctly show the right name, but i do get a notice/warning: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in //file location//

Comment: I'd advise moving the query to your Locatie model and trying that way - using the 2nd part of my answer.  Let me know if you'd like an example :-) Alternatively, try var_dump()'ing out the objects ($obj) and you'll see how it's structured.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try that :), also i found some doctrine documentation on hydration so that will help too. Ill check back after i try your changes :)

Comment: Just wondering, how to use the self::create("l"), culd you give me an example?

this is what i have:http://pastebin.com/cQzxpEP8

Comment: Updated to include an example :-)

Comment: I dont see it :P

I did get it to work btw, the query is still in the action, but it works. The error i posted about is because the organisation can be NULL, i added a check to see if its set before php echoes it and now it works. I would still like to see how i can put the query in my model though ;)

Comment: Thanks for accepting :-) you can't see the edit I made to my answer? There's an example about using the query inside the Doctrine table class for your model.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, stupid me. Thank you very much for your help! It works :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to get some value from the result DoctrineRecord object I advise to use var_dump($obj->toArray()) method to get clear view of the object structure. After that you can use several types of getters to retrive what you want (e.g. $obj->A->b, $obj->getA()->getB() etc..)

Comment: Thank you for you comment, this actually helped me an a completely different problem :)